# DRY serialization in C#: abstract, delegates or reflection?

Tags: c#, serialization, delegates, dry, abstract

I'm (de)serializing some datastructures for a network-multiplayer game, and for each datastructure that's to be (de)serialized, I want to define the order of (de)serialization only once for maintainability.

I can use C#'s abstract class methods to achieve my goal, but there's several problems with doing so:

1. performance: I'd rather not incur the boxing involved with the use of "ref" parameters to built-in types
2. performance: adding an additional abstract method call to each (de)serialization operation isn't ideal either
3. extra typing: I have to needlessly initialize all variables I'm deserializing because C# won't allow me to pass "ref" and "out" parameters interchangeably

How can I avoid duplicating the definition of a datastructure's (de)serialization while also avoiding some or all of the above issues?

(I toyed with delegates and reflection, but this solution came to me most readily):

```
public struct ControllerSnapshot
{
    public Vector2 m_lStick;

    static private void Op(ref float lStickX, ref float lStickY, Op<float> op)
    {
        //define (de)serialization order here once and only once
        lStickX = op.Invoke(lStickX);
        lStickY = op.Invoke(lStickY);
    }
    public ControllerSnapshot(uLink.BitStream bitStream)
    {   
        OpRead<float> opRead = new OpRead<float>(bitStream);
        float lStickX,lStickY;
        lStickX = lStickY = 0.0f;//3.can't use "out"; have to match Op's "ref" params
        Op(ref lStickX,ref lStickY,opRead);

        m_lStick = new Vector2(lStickX,lStickY);
    }
    public void Serialize(uLink.BitStream bitStream)
    {
        OpWrite<float> opWrite = new OpWrite<float>(bitStream);
        Op(ref m_lStick.x, ref m_lStick.y, opWrite);
    }
};

//in order to make the above work this needs to be defined:
abstract class Op<T>
{
    public Op(uLink.BitStream bitStream)
    {
        m_bitStream = bitStream;
    }
    abstract public T Invoke(T arg);

    protected uLink.BitStream m_bitStream;
}
class OpRead<T>:Op<T>
{
    public OpRead(uLink.BitStream bitStream) : base(bitStream) { }
    override public T Invoke(T arg)
    {
        return m_bitStream.Read<T>();
    }
}
class OpWrite<T>:Op<T>
{
    public OpWrite(uLink.BitStream bitStream) : base(bitStream) { }
    override public T Invoke(T arg)
    {
        m_bitStream.Write<T>(arg);
        return arg;
    }
}   

//by contrast, the "obvious" code duplicates the order of (de)serialization, which I
//want to avoid, especially as (de)serialization becomes increasingly complex:
public ControllerSnapshot(uLink.BitStream bitStream)
{
    float lStickX,lStickY;
    lStickX = bitStream.Read<float>();
    lStickY = bitStream.Read<float>();

    m_lStick = new Vector2(lStickX,lStickY);
}
public void Serialize(uLink.BitStream bitStream)
{
    bitStream.Write<float>(m_lStick.x);
    bitStream.Write<float>(m_lStick.y);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use any standard serialization approach? Why they don't fit your needs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "standard serialization approach", so I don't know if it fits my needs.  What approach are you referencing?

Comment: I mean: binary serialization (see `BinaryFormatter` class), XML serialization (see `XmlSerializer` class), data contracts serialization (see `DataContractSerializer`, `DataContractJsonSerializer` and `NetDataContractSerializer` classes). It looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I have no firsthand experience with any of these classes (until recently I've primarily been a C++ programmer, and a "light" user of languages like C#), but my first instinct as that since this project is relying on a networking library (uLink) for which we don't have the source, I suspect these classes won't be compatible with datastructures like uLink.BitStream.  Do you think I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't know, what is `uLink`, but if it can transfer array of bytes, you can use any serializer, because, ultimately, the result of serialization is an array of bytes. By the way, as @zmbq mentioned, Protobufs is a good option here, too.

Comment: I apologize -- my question was written incompletely.  The most important aspect of any solution is to maintain zero (de)serialization bandwidth overhead.  ProtoBufs and BinaryFormatter both seem to use some metadata in addition to the "payload" data, and XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer and NetDataContractSerializer are all xml-based, which will consume more bandwidth than a straightforward binary serialization.  I wonder if it would make sense to move the question to gamedev.stackexchange.com; maybe the strict processor/bandwidth requirements are unusual.  Thanks for the thoughts though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think a virtual method call is going to make any sort of difference here - you are serializing your object for transport over the network. The additional couple of nanoseconds are meaningless.

Your proposed solution makes you repeat yourself, too - you still have to specify your properties in both serialization and deserialization.

The only way you can avoid that is by somehow specifying which fields should be serialized and use some sort of reflection - much like what .NET's serializers have been doing for a decade.

UPDATE:

*Actually*, why not use Google's [Protobufs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)?

Comment: You're probably right that the virtual method call is not a significant performance problem, but we're running at 60fps, so I try to avoid any unnecessary processing when it's reasonable to do so.  Also a good point about my repeating the specification of the properties -- I think that this repetition, while not ideal, is very unlikely to lead to maintenance bugs, whereas duplicating the ordering of (de)serialization is a classic maintenance bug scenario.  Would you say that .NET's serialization reflection is a much better approach here?

Comment: I think that your second version - the short concise one - is the fastest you'll get. Unless you use something someone else already optimized. Just remembered such a thing.

Comment: Agreed that the second Read/Write version would run fastest, but I'll happily run imperceptibly slower -- let's say up to 0.00016ms slower, not that it'd be easy to measure this sort of "death of a thousand cuts" performance cost :P -- if I can avoid even a few hours of maintenance bug-fixing over the course of the project.

Comment: Good thought; do you think Google's Protobufs will be compatible with a third-party library like uLink?

Comment: I don't know, you'll have to check.

Comment: Also, if you end up using your own serialization, try to add some safety measures - serialize the value as well as some sort of variation of the name, so when you deserialize you can find out you're not in the right order and throw an exception right away, instead of flying backwards.

Comment: I apologize -- my question was written incompletely.  The most important aspect of any solution is to maintain zero (de)serialization bandwidth overhead.  ProtoBufs and BinaryFormatter both seem to use some metadata in addition to the "payload" data, and XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer and NetDataContractSerializer are all xml-based, which will consume more bandwidth than a straightforward binary serialization.  You did answer my question as it was originally posed -- is it customary to mark this answer as correct and repost an updated question, or to simply update my current question?

Comment: You should ask your question again, this one has too many comments already.